# can I edit log_reuse_wait_desc column value in sys.database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

My database log file has grown and eaten up all space available on the disk, I am not able to shrink it. I found out that in sys.database table values of log_reuse_wait_desc field is 'Active_Transaction' for this database. Can I change it manually in table to 'Nothing' and try shrinking it again ?

Comment: Update : I just stopped my application services and checked this field value again. It got reset to 'Nothing' and I was able to shrink it.

Comment: No, the `sys` catalog is off-limits - it's a **system** catalog, i.e. it's only the "system" (SQL Server itself) that can provide information into that catalog schema. You have no means of directly modifying any of that informatoin

Comment: there might be a command to doing that. check out DBCC or sp_configure or other stuff